# How to listen to top level (window) event on React Native?

Tags: react-native

Is there react-native equivalent of `window.addEventListener('click', fn)`?

I want to listen to the most top level event.

For a small popover UI element, it wants to listen to all touch events outside of its popover container, and  dismiss itself when outside has been clicked.

Comment: I can't speak from experience on this, but this might be a good starting point. Check out the nativeEvents. May not do exactly what you're hoping for, but if you create a responder view, you should be able to accomplish the same thing. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html#responder-lifecycle

Comment: Also, I don't fully get it, but I just came across this and it seems relevant, so maybe it will be helpful. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/425a7f7a84a88dc5303df8c23ea382041672618c/docs/NativeModulesAndroid.md#getting-activity-result-from-startactivityforresult